# OpenGL and SDL_Image texture issue

Tags: opengl, mingw, sdl, glew, sdl-image

I'm using glew 1.1.0, SDL_image 2.0 and mingw(Code::Blocks, Windows).  I'm trying to import an .png file by using SDL_Image and to make it a texture and display to the screen i use OpenGL. When i run the program it displays a pure white square, it has the same width and height of the image im trying to import, but it's pure white. i looked over the code for about 30 minutes straight and the code looks fine, and it never gave me any errors execpt "Error initializing OpenGL! invalid value".

my main.cpp:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>

using namespace std;

void init();
void Render();

bool ex;
bool akey;


SDL_Event e;
SDL_Window *win = NULL;
GLuint txID;

int x, y, w, h;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
init();

while(!ex)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
    {
        if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            ex = true;
        }
       Render();
    }
}
}

void init()
{


SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 0);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

win = SDL_CreateWindow("Demo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);


SDL_GLContext cont = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);
SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
glewInit();

glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
glViewport( 0.f, 0.f, 640, 480);

glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho( 0.0, 640, 480, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0 );

  glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();

  glClearColor( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );

glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
SDL_Surface *sur = IMG_Load("ef.png");
w = 40;
h = 60;


glGenTextures( 1, &txID );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, txID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sur->pixels);
GLenum error = glGetError();

if( error != GL_NO_ERROR )
{
    printf( "Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString( error ) );

}
//Set texture parameters
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

//Unbind texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);

}


void Render()
{
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(20, 20, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, txID);

glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2f( 0.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f(0.f, 0.f);
    glTexCoord2f( 1.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f(w, 0.f);
    glTexCoord2f( 1.f, 1.f ); glVertex2f(w, h);
    glTexCoord2f( 0.f, 1.f ); glVertex2f(0.f, h);
glEnd();


SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);


}
```

This is the image I'm trying to load:

[image]

The program and the error, as you can see the white box is where the image is supposed to be.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an `invalid value` because you're passing `4` as the `internalFormat`. Passing `4` represents `GL_TRIANGLES` which isn't a valid format.

[Check the documentation for valid formats.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)

You probably meant to pass `GL_RGBA`.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sur->pixels);
```

> The weirdest part about this is i got to work on my old laptop

The reason it worked on your old laptop, is because the driver was being clever.

> It still gives me the same error and still renders a pure white square

First of all instead of setting `w` and `h` yourself, you can get them from the `SDL_Surface`.

```
SDL_Surface *sur = IMG_Load("someimage.jpg");

GLuint txID = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &txID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, txID);

int mode = GL_RGB;
if(sur->format->BytesPerPixel == 4)
    mode = GL_RGBA;

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mode, sur->w, sur->h, 0, mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sur->pixels);
```

I now noticed that you're targeting OpenGL 4.0. So the `invalid value` could also be caused by you trying to use the fixed-function pipeline, while having a OpenGL 4.0 context.

While I would recommend staying away from the fixed-function pipeline in general. Try requesting an OpenGL 2.0 context and see if that resolves the problem.

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 0);
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error and still renders a pure white square. The weirdest part about this is i got to work on my old laptop a while back and now on this new desktop it wont work.